# Should the [taxes] tag be merged as a synonym for [tax-law]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

At the time of writing, **[taxes](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes)** is [tagged to 64 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes), whereas **[tax-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax-law)** is [tagged to 482](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax-law).

Unlike the four other [tax-related tags](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags) that all relate to a particular sub-category, [taxes](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) and [tax-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax-law) both cover the same generic subject matter and, as this is LawSE, it seems appropriate to prefer the use the tag with "law" in its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Merge and synonymize

It seems like taxes is used as shorthand for tax-law or any sort of tax-obligation prescribed under such tax-laws.